# Node-sass does not understand tilde

Tags: node.js, angular, sass

Exploring the `angular-cli` for RC1 of Angular2 released recently I faced strange problem: `node-sass` within sass plugin in the `angular-cli` does not parses `~` before the package name throwing following error:

```
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ~@angular2-material/core/style/theme-functions
```

It happens during compiling the following code:

```
@import "~@angular2-material/core/style/theme-functions";
```

If I remove tilde everything will be ok. Is it the right behavior, or there is a path to make `node-sass` understand `~`?

**P.S.** I use WebStorm, and it prefers using `~` too. If tilde is omitted it complains to unability of resolving path. And after some googling I found that using code without tilde is legacy and `~` should be used as best practice. Is it right?

Comment: Tilde path resolving is something that webpack does, node-sass doesn't have such a resolver built in. sass-loader for webpack has this, but not with that strange `@` symbol. You can write your own import resolution though - https://github.com/sass/node-sass#importer--v200---experimental

Comment: @DominicTobias, thanks, it works. Can you write it as answer? About `@`-symbol - it is a part of name of npm package splitted up to parts downloading separately. E.g. `angular2` package was splitted up to `@angular/core`, `@angular/http` etc. In terms of node-sass it is just a part of folder name.

Comment: ah I see - and sure, thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Tilde path resolving is something that webpack does, node-sass doesn't have such a resolver built in. [sass-loader](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader) for webpack has this. You can [write your own import resolution](http://github.com/sass/node-sass#importer--v200---experimental) alternatively.

Just for completeness here's how you might do it without webpack/sass-loader using a custom importer:

```
function importer(url, prev, done) {
  if (url[0] === '~') {
    url = path.resolve('node_modules', url.substr(1));
  }

  return { file: url };
}
```

Comment: Do you need to add a check to ensure the 2nd character in the URL is _not_ a forward slash to avoid processing URLs that start with `~/file`? So perhaps... `if (url[0] === '~' && url[1] !== '/')` ?

Comment: As in `~/` representing the home directory on the users computer? I would personally be fine with `~/file` resolving to `./node_modules/file` still

Comment: Correct. I guess it depends on the environment where you're using Node-Sass. My understanding is that webpack, Angular CLI and others are using "~/" to reference app root...so probably just something to consider when creating importer. FWIW to future Googlers, sass-loader does seem to check for the "/" in their implementation: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#imports

Comment: I'm missing something here, where am I supposed to put this function?

Comment: helped me alot understanding node-sass importer feature. thanks!

Comment: @azerafati If you are calling `sass.render({...})` you can add it there as an option. Otherwise, if you are calling `node-sass` from the commandline or from a package script, you can add the option `--importer node-sass.importer.js` with a file that exports the function: `const path = require('path'); module.exports = function(url, prev, done) {...}`

Answer (score 9):

I just had to install the node-sass-tilde-importer package:

```
npm install node-sass-tilde-importer --save
```

And then change my scss script to:

```
node-sass --watch style.scss --importer=node_modules/node-sass-tilde-importer style.css
```

Here are some relevant parts of my package.json file:

```
{

  [...]

  "scripts": {
    "scss": "node-sass --watch style.scss --importer=node_modules/node-sass-tilde-importer style.css"
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bootstrap-material-design": "^4.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "node-sass-tilde-importer": "^1.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: There is typo in the install command, but I can't edit it because edits have to be at least 6 characters (dumb!) and it is just missing an 'n'