# Simplify SCSS @import paths with WebPack 2

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, sass-loader

I currently have a project setup that uses the [sass-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader) WebPack plugin. This means that we can easily import SCSS from node_modules using the following:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins/breakpoints";
```

Is there a way I can create a shortcut like above, to make imports of my own SCSS files a bit simpler. I would like to be able to convert for example:

```
@import '../../../../styles/app';
```

to

```
@import '~styles/app';
```

or even

```
@import 'styles/app';
```

I currently have the following resolver settings in my webpack.config.js:

```
// ....
resolve: {
    alias: {
        selectize$: path.join(__dirname, './node_modules/selectize/dist/js/selectize')
    },
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    modules: ['./node_modules']
},
resolveLoader: {
    modules: ['./node_modules']
}
//....
```

Comment: Tried adding styles: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/styles') to resolve.alias, but it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it working, I changed the node-sass *importer* options through sass-loader to allow loading for example `styles/app` from `src/styles/app`

```
{
    exclude: [ /* excludes */ ],
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: [
        'exports-loader?module.exports.toString()',
        'css-loader',
        'postcss-loader',
        {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
                importer: (url, prev, done) => {
                    if (url[0] === '~') {
                        url = path.resolve('node_modules', url.substr(1));
                    } else if (url.startsWith('styles/')) {
                        url = path.resolve('src/', url);
                    }

                    return {file: url}
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This way, WebPack is happy, and after adding the *src* path in WebStorm as a *Resource Root*, autocompletion still works, and WebStorm is not complaining that it can't find the file.

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106230/node-sass-does-not-understand-tilde) was quite useful in resolving my issue.

Comment: Wow... this solution is a diamond!